# How can I read a text file which has a strings n the first row and numbers and symbols in the next rows on octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a text file which contains titles for each column on the first row, and then numbers and symbols (such as "pi" for pi=3.14 or a distance represented with "d" or angle represented with "beta") And I

The text file is as follows:

[Example of text file to be read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2jKK.jpg)

It works perfectly in MATLAB using **readtable('text.txt')** and I obtain the following:

[Result in MATLAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj1VE.jpg)

But, I am not able to get the same result in Octave. Is there a function in Octave that allows me to extract all the information from the text file similarly to MATLAB?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read such file using textread in octave, see

https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/textread.html

Comment: This function "textread" has many forms to specify the file format. Do you know how it's possible to define that the first row are just titles and the other rows are values and symbolic values? Thank you